# Access project build variables in init.gradle task

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to figure out, how to set variables in build.gradle and access that varible in init.gradle script.

Please find below sample build script :-

```
gradle.allprojects{

    task CommonTasks{
        println "CommonTasks - loaded"
    }

    CommonTasks.doFirst{
        println "CommonTasks - doFirst : here i want to use variable, that is declared in project build"
    }

    CommonTasks.doLast{
        println "CommonTasks - doLast"
    }

}
```

Also find below sample project build :-

```
apply plugin : 'java'

//some-where here i want to pass a variable in CommonTasks
clean.dependsOn CommonTasks
```

Please suggest, how to access project build.gradle variables(say, String or File type for example) on init.gradle page.

Answer (score 1):

Largely, you just need to be careful about which phases all of the code runs in. Gradle has 3 phases when you run a `gradle <some task>` command.

- Initialization - processes `init.gradle` scripts, `settings.gradle` scripts, and generally just gets the project structure defined
- Configuration - processes `build.gradle` scripts for all projects
- Execution - executes the requested tasks

Importantly you can delay execution of code in your `init.gradle` script into later phases. I included print statements in the example below to help illustrate when this code executes.

One option for what you want is to declare the property in the init phase on the task or project (my example shows it on the task). This way you are sure that the property is defined by the time you reference it in your `doFirst`. Your build.gradle just needs to set that variable at configuration time.

**init.gradle**

```
println 'init.gradle: In initialization phase'
gradle.allprojects {
  task CommonTasks {
    println 'init.gradle: In configuration phase'
    ext.myVar = null
    println "Value of myVar=${myVar}"
    doFirst {
      println 'init.gradle: In execution phase - doFirst'
      println "Value of myVar=${myVar}"
    }
    doLast {
      println 'init.gradle: In execution phase - doLast'
    }
  }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'

// set the value
CommonTasks.myVar = 'buildValue'

clean.dependsOn CommonTasks
```

This should print out `myVar=buildValue` upon execution.